# How can I ensure that a shell script executed as a child process in Node.js and Express stops running when the curl command is terminated?

Tags: node.js, express, child-process

New to nodejs and js here. I'm trying to create a service which will use expressjs to expose an endpoint which in turn will trigger a shell script on the server. While this script is in execution, all of the standard output and error contents will be streamed to the client. Below is the endpoint that I intend to expose :

```js
router.post('/stream-script', (req, res) => {
  // Get the script to run from the request
  script = req.body.script;
  shell = spawn(script, {shell : true});

  shell.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    res.write(data);
    // res.flush();
  })

  shell.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    res.write(data);
    // res.flush();
  })

  shell.on('close', (code) => {
    res.write(`child process exited with code ${code}\n`);
    res.end();
  });

  shell.on('error', (error) => {
      res.status(500).send(`Error occurred: ${error.message}\n`);
  });

});
```

Now, the place where I am stuck at is that I was expecting that the process will get killed if I send the interrupt or stop signal to the curl command that I'm using to test the functionality here. But, after quitting the curl command I can still see the process spawned running in the background.

```bash
rookieintraining@Swatah:~$ curl -N --location 'http://localhost:3000/shell/stream-script' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{ "script" : "free -mh -s 5" }'
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.2Gi       5.5Gi       2.0Mi       741Mi       6.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.2Gi       5.5Gi       2.0Mi       741Mi       6.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.2Gi       5.5Gi       2.0Mi       741Mi       6.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.2Gi       5.5Gi       2.0Mi       741Mi       6.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.2Gi       5.5Gi       2.0Mi       741Mi       6.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.4Gi       1.2Gi       5.5Gi       2.0Mi       741Mi       6.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
^C
rookieintraining@Swatah:~$ ps -ef | grep free
rookiei+  3297  3277  0 21:51 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c free -mh -s 5
rookiei+  3298  3297  0 21:51 pts/0    00:00:00 free -mh -s 5
rookiei+  3301  2532  0 21:51 pts/6    00:00:00 grep --color=auto free
```

I have tried using the 'close' event on the expressjs server, but to no avail. On adding this event listener, I don't get any output but can see the processes still running in the background :

```js
req.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Request closed by the client');
    // Perform any necessary cleanup or handling
    res.end();
  });
```

Can anyone please help me with this? or share pointers to the approach which can help me achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance.